# Laravel 5.4 routes/api.php POST MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am writting APIs for android/ios using Laravel 5.4. My simple webservice signUp which is working perfectly on localhost not working on live server and giving

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException on POST methods

GET call works perfect .

Route code

```
Route::post('/signUp',['uses'=>'API_UserController@userSignUp']);
```

Attached is screen shot link of my postman.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/060IF.png

Comment: I see no screenshot but did you attached the csrf token?

Comment: clear the cache `php artisan cache:clear` and route cache `php artisan route:cache` on your server, and then try

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR i have tried that

Comment: add the code, how you are calling this route

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR i am calling from postman, its a POST request

Comment: where is screenshot?

Comment: have you disable the csrf token

Comment: @DestinatioN Sorry I think i missed the attachement but its simple call from postman using POST method

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR Yes like this protected $except = [
        'api/*'
    ]; in the Kernal.php

Comment: @DestinatioN i have added screenshot link

Comment: @MehulKuriya  i have added screenshot link

Comment: @MujeebUrRehman add a screenshot of headers too please

Comment: Please add complete route code

Comment: @DestinatioN here is header screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhcYI.png

Comment: Like I already said there is no csrf token. You have to pass the token or disable csrf token

Comment: @DestinatioN i already disabled csrf on api routes in Kernal.php i.e $except = [ 'api/*' ];

Comment: Okay, to @RAUSHANKUMAR you said that you set $except inside Kernel. Try to set $except in the VerifyCsrfToken.php

Comment: @DestinatioN Sorry i have already added in VerifyCsrfToken.php but still it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is quick example of flow  try this

```
   <form action="{{url('v1/userSignUp')}}" class="validation"  method="post" 
    accept-charset="utf-8">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div>
                    // your required form field
      <input type="submit"  value="Add Category"  class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
          </form>
```

and in your route add this

```
         Route::get('/signUp', function () {
          return view('yourviewpagename');
          });
         Route::post('/signUp','API_UserController@userSignUp');
```

and in your API_UserController

```
    public function userSignUp()
     {
    dd(request->all());
}
```

Comment: i have already told you that it is just api call , i am wrting apis for mobile apps and that does not include any views or form . i am testing it on postman ...... btw thanks for your struggle

Answer (score 0):

@Mujeeb Ur Rehman  Post method is use to send data and get method is use to access data in view or just to render view.

```
  eg:-route:post('/home',xxController@xx);
  route:get('/home1',xxController@xx);
```

error which you are getting is because suppose if you url it like this localhost/xx/home your framework think to access data or post data framework get confuse in this

Comment: Sorry i didnt understand completely , could you please tell me how should i write my route ?

Comment: @MujeebUrRehman if you want to submit to database or any logic for eg:- comparison or condition anything which require bussiness logic i mean to say if you want to send some data to controller then you require post method which is not render on view i mean it will work in backend but if you want to see something on frontend then use get method your method will work if your send it from your render view but it will not work if you try to access it from directly url use this one           Route::post('/signUp','API_UserController@userSignUp');  hope this will help

Comment: :post('/signUp','API_UserController@userSignUp'); also didnt worked :(

Comment: @MujeebUrRehman could you solve your problem? I have also the same issue!!

Answer (score 0):

just use like this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
     Route::post('/signUp','API_UserController@userSignUp');
    });
```

when you hit via postman tour URL is http://your_domain/api/v1/signUp so just add a prefix it will automatically add with your URL. in route group u can also use many other things like namespace, middleware etc. Example :

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'any_depend_on_your_project_structure', 'middleware' => 'any_middleware', 'prefix' => 'v1'], function() {
// your routes
});
```

Comment: I am using prefix and namespace and they are working fine for GET api call but  POST api call gives MethodNotFoundException

Comment: can you attach a screenshot for your get success call

Comment: here is screenshot link for successful GET call https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd7es.png

Comment: during your post call header contain two data can you show them or check them again that there is nothing wrong with them